# Let $x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}$ and $x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}$ are rational numbers. Show that $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is rational.

Tags: solution-verification, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

> $x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}$ and $x^4+\dfrac{1}{x^4}$ are rational numbers. Prove that $x+\dfrac{1}{x}$ is rational number.

**My solution:**

> $x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}=\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1\right)$
>
> $x^4+\dfrac{1}{x^4}=x^4+2+\dfrac{1}{x^4}-2=\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)^2-1-1=\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1\right)\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+1\right)-1$
>
> Because $x^4+\dfrac{1}{x^4}$ is rational number so
> $\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1\right)$ is rational number too and
> $x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}$ is rational number so
> $\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ is rational number.

Am I wrong? Please check my solution, thank you.

Comment: Why do you think is $\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1\right)$ a rational number?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: $x^4+\dfrac{1}{x^4}$ is rational number so $\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1\right)$ is rational number too. I don't think this is necessarily true.

Comment: There's more work to do.

Comment: @seayellow oh i got it, thank you

Comment: Hint: Consider a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @seayellow, give a counterexample .

Comment: @Sukhoi234 $1=\sqrt{3}^2-1-1$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3407996/11619) but nowhere near being a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the commenters pointed out, a problem in your argument is that the implication
"$(x^4+x^{-4})$ is rational" $\implies$ "$(x^2+x^{-2})$ is rational" is false.
For example, it is possible that $x^2+x^{-2}=\sqrt5$ when, by your tricks, $x^4+x^{-4}=(x^2+x^{-2})^2-2=3$, a rational number. Of course, in this case $x^3+x^{-3}$ fails to be rational, but this underlines a problem in your logic.

One commenter suggested using a contrapositive argument. This may be a possibility, but a bit delicate to manage.

---

My favorite approach (that generalizes to several variants of this question) is somewhat high browed in the sense that it uses properties of algebraic field extensions. Outlining it for the benefit of the readers familiar with that theory.

- As $x^3+1/x^3=q_3\in\Bbb{Q}$ the number $x$ is a zero of the polynomial
  $P_3(T)=T^6-q_3T^3+1$ with rational coefficients. Therefore $x$ is an algebraic number. Let $m(T)\in\Bbb{Q}[T]$ be its minimal polynomial.
- The other zeros of $P_3(T)$ are $x^{\pm1}\omega^j$, $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ a primitive third root of unity, $j\in\{0,1,2\}$. Therefore the zeros of $m(T)$
  are among these numbers.
- But, as $x^4+1/x^4=q_4\in\Bbb{Q}$, $x$ is also a zero of the polynomial
  $P_4(T)=T^8-q_4T^4+1$. The zeros of $P_4(T)$ are seen to be $x^{\pm1}i^j$, $j\in\{0,1,2,3\}$.
- The zeros of $m(T)$ are common zeros of both $P_3(T)$ and $P_4(T)$, so they can only be $x^{\pm1}$.
- But $$r(T):=(T-x)(T-\frac1x)=T^2-(x+\frac1x)T+1.$$ Either $x$ is rational, when the claim is trivial, or $m(T)=r(T)$, implying that the coefficients of $r(T)$ are rational. Here $x+\dfrac1x$ is the coefficient of the linear term of $r(T)$ and we are done in this case as well.

---

Toying with Mathematica gives the following elementary method.

Write $u=x+\dfrac1x$. We are given that (see the linked thread)
$$
A=x^3+\frac1{x^3}=u^3-3u
$$
and
$$
B=x^4+\frac1{x^4}=u^4-4u^2+2
$$
are rational. Hence so is the quantity
$$
\frac{A^3+AB-3A}{B^2-1}=u.
$$

---

Explaining the reason why some formula like the one above writing $u$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ must exist. Let's treat $u$ as a variable, an element transcendental over $\Bbb{Q}$. Write $F=\Bbb{Q}(u)$ for the field of rational functions. It has subfields $K_1=\Bbb{Q}(A)$ and $K_2=\Bbb{Q}(B)$. We immediately see that the respective extension degrees are $[F:K_1]=3$ and $[F:K_2]=4$. By the tower law, the only possibility is then that the compositum $K_1K_2=\Bbb{Q}(A,B)$ must be all of $F$. Consequently $u$ can be written as a rational function (with rational coefficients) in $A$ and $B$. Observe that the representation is not unique, because $A$ and $B$ are algebraically dependent over $\Bbb{Q}$ given that they both reside in the same transcendence degree one extension $F$.

Comment: A particular generalization concerns the variants where, for example, $x^3+x^{-3}$ and $x^4+x^{-4}$ are known to be integers. Then we similarly see that $x$ must be an algebraic integer. Consequently $x+1/x$ is a rational integer. That is, an integer in the usual sense. An induction the proves that $x^m+x^{-m}$ is an integer for all natural numbers $m$.

Comment: ^... we similarly see that both $x$ and $1/x$ must be algebraic integers.

Comment: The first method shows that for any (a,b)=1, given $x^a+\frac1{x^a}, x^b+\frac1{x^b}$ are both rational, $x+\frac1x$ must be rational number too.

Comment: Correct, @ZhaohuiDu. The variant considering algebraic integers shows that if $x^a+x^{-a}$ and $x^b+x^{-b}$ are integers for some coprime pair $(a,b)$ then $x+x^{-1}$ is also an integer. Consequently $x^n+x^{-n}$ is an integer for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: We could use the fact that $P_3(T)$ and $P_4(T)$ have only two common roots x and $\frac1x$ to reach the result $gcd(P_3(T),P_4(T))=T^2-(x+\frac1x)T+1$ so $x+\frac1x$ is an integer. This approach looks more elementary than "algebraic integers"

Comment: Or we can write $$u=\frac{p^2q-p^2-q+2}{p}\in\mathbb Q.$$

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu True, but you need a tiny bit of theory of algebraic integers. Namely that the minimal polynomial (normalized to be monic) necessarily has integer coefficients. Or some substitute of that. At least when I was thinking about the $a=n$, $b=n+1$ variant in olympic training I recall needing exactly that. Only later, when I was idly revisiting that problem, I realized the trick with the common zeros of the two polynomials.

Answer (score 9):

Let $a_k=x^k+\frac1{x^k}$， we have
$\begin{cases}a_1a_4=a_5+a_3\\a_2a_3=a_5+a_1\\a_1a_3=a_4+a_2\end{cases}$

By writing $a_3=u,a_4=v$, we could rewrite the fomula as
$\begin{cases}va_1+0a_2-a_5=u\\a_1-ua_2+a_5=0\\ua_1-a_2+0a_5=v\end{cases}$
Solving the linear equation of $a_1,a_2,a_5$ we could get they're all rational number

Comment: Simpler than mine (+1). Proving that the determinant of your system is non-zero may not be immediate :-)

Comment: Yes. We need check the determinant which is $-u^2+u+1$ which is non-zero since the root of polynomial $-x^2+x+1$ is irrational.

Comment: Hmm. I got $-u^2+v+1$ as the determinant. That may be a bit more difficult to handle.

Answer (score 9):

I constructed a possible elementary algebraic way:

Let,

$$\begin{cases}x+\frac 1x=v,\thinspace v \not \in \mathbb Q\\
x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=u,\thinspace u\in\mathbb R\\
x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=p,\thinspace p\in\mathbb Q\\
x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}=q,\thinspace q\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

This implies,

$$pv=u+q\not\in \mathbb Q\implies u\not\in\mathbb Q\\$$

Then we have,

$$\begin{align}&uq=p^2-2+u\\
\implies &uq-u=p^2-2\\
\implies &u=\frac{p^2-2}{q-1}\in\mathbb Q\\
&\thinspace \text{A contradiction.}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your recent editing :-)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to write this answer with the thought that it might be cleaner than my previous answer.

We have,

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}x+\frac 1x=u,\thinspace u \in \mathbb R\\
x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=v,\thinspace v\in\mathbb R\\
x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=p,\thinspace p\in\mathbb Q\\
x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}=q,\thinspace q\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}\\ \implies &vq=p^2-2+v\\
\implies &vq-v=p^2-2\\
\implies &v=\frac{p^2-2}{q-1}\in\mathbb Q\\
\implies &up=q+v\\
\implies &u=\frac{q+v}{p}\in\mathbb Q.\end{align}$$

---

**Final answer:**

$$u=\frac{p^2q-p^2-q+2}{p}\in\mathbb Q.$$

Comment: This is surely a cleaner way!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for reviewing..

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Now I think we can derive your formula $A,B$ from the formula $p,q$.  It just occurred to me now.

Answer (score 2):

With $\alpha= x+\frac{1}{x}$ we get
$$x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} =\alpha^3 - 3 \alpha = u\\
x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4} = \alpha^4 - 4 \alpha^2 + 2 = v$$

The polynomials $t^3 - 3 t - u$ and $t^4 - 4 t^2 + 2 - v$ have a common root $\alpha$. If that were the only common root, then their gcd $t-\alpha$ would have rational coefficients. So assume that they have another common root $\beta \ne \alpha$. Now we get the system
$$(\alpha^3 - 3 \alpha) -(\beta^3 - 3 \beta) = 0\\
(\alpha^4 - 4 \alpha^2) -(\beta^4 - 4 \beta^2) = 0$$
that is
$$(\alpha - \beta) (\alpha^2 + \alpha \beta + \beta^2 - 3)=0 \\
(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha+ \beta) (\alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 4)=0$$
and since $\alpha- \beta \ne 0$ we get finitely many solutions
$\pm (\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}), \pm(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}, -\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}(2+\sqrt{3}) )$ and its conjugate.  For neither of these $\alpha$'s do we get both rational values for $x^3 + 1/x^3$, $x^4 + 1/x^4$.